# Mapping .css and image files through asp.net even with Integrated Pipeline and asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7

I've got some complex routes setup in my asp.net mvc 3 project, unit tested and working on development. For the most part they're working with IIS7 and Integrated Pipeline and having mapAllRequests=true.

But I'm also doing some funky routing with 'some' of the requests for images and css. I'm not sure if it's the logic or if it's IIS taking over when it see's css or img files. I want IIS to take over if it finds the static file otherwise send it to the mvc routing, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not with app pool in integrated mode - all requests are passed to the application. By default, MVC does not route requests for static files (it maps url-paths to them just like non-mvc asp.net, which is the behavior that you want).

You can change that behavior (`routes.RouteExistingFiles = true`) if you want to do something special within responses to static files. More info about this property:

[ASP.NET MVC RouteExistingFiles question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249511/asp-net-mvc-routeexistingfiles-question)

[Considerations when turning on RouteExistingFiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402264/considerations-when-turning-on-routeexistingfiles)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc668201.aspx

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Im not sure this is what I was asking for. The files don't actually exist at all. Thanks.

Comment: As I said, it works correctly in Visual Studio and the unit tests work correctly aswell. There must be some difference between IIS routing and the routing in VS.